# What NPM command should users run if the package.json file has been updated?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

If I update the package.json file in an NPM workflow app, what command do existing users run to update their local node_modules dependencies?

To start using it, they run:

```
$ npm install
```

So what do they run if there is a change to the package.json file? Or do they just delete the folder and re-run the `npm install` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To re-validate the package.json and install adjusted versions or new packages:

```
$ npm install
```

---

The one thing this *won't* do is remove packages that aren't in package.json. To do that, run:

```
$ npm prune
```

---

If you've only changed package versions and not added new packages:

```
$ npm update
```

---

If you you've updated a *specific* package version:

```
$ npm update {packagename}
```

Comment: Hey Brandon, thanks! I shall put this in the documentation.

Comment: What if the user doesn’t want to check the history of `package.json` to see if things were added or removed and just wants to run a command to get `node_modules` to match the `package.json`?

Comment: Why would you care if the history of package.json is checked? This does the job and syncs downloaded packages to match package.json.

Answer (score 0):

You should either do

```
npm install && npm prune
```

or

```
npm upgrade && npm prune
```

`npm install` will be faster than `npm upgrade` because it only updates packages in `node_modules` if `package.json` demands a newer version. `npm uprade`, on the other hand, will download updates to dependencies if they are available, which may include bug fixes. For `≥npm-5`, you should use `npm install` because `npm upgrade` will have the side-effect of modifying any [`package-lock.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json) file which should not be modified unless if you are the package’s maintainer.

`npm prune` is necessary because the updates to `package.json` may have removed dependencies. If you do not run `npm prune`, packages installed by a prior version of `package.json` will remain in the `node_modules` directory that would not be there if you freshly downloaded/cloned the project and ran `npm install`. Due to how some packages conditionally call `require()` or even scan the `node_modules` directory, leaving packages which were removed from `package.json` can result in unexpected behavior.